# Here, how can I use if statement with string.Contains()?

Tags: c#

I am tring to validate the array each element using if not exist. But 'if not contain'  not working as expect. Please look on the below gif image. How can I validate properly ?

```
var PartnerTypeName =
    pageVm
        .Form1
        .PartnerTypeName
        .Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Distinct();

if ((PartnerTypeName.Any("PSUD".Contains)
        || PartnerTypeName.Any("PDST".Contains)
        || PartnerTypeName.Any("PDLR".Contains))
    && (!PartnerTypeName.Any("SERP".Contains)
        || !PartnerTypeName.Any("Contractors".Contains)))
{
    /*here the logic*/
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text. Code from images cannot be copied/pasted or indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line as `PartnerTypeName.Any("PSUD".Contains)` might not be doing what you expect it to. In this snippet, you are passing the `Contains` method of the string instance `"PSUD"` as a predicate to the `Any` method. 
This means each string in the array is passed to the the contains of that particular string. In this case if the array contains for example `"U"` or `"SU"`, the Any would be true. Of course I could be mistaken and this is intentional behaviour.

But this is not the main reason the logic isn't working. That is because the last `!SERP || !Contracters` should be `&&`. That is, assuming you don't want the evaluation to be true if either one is in the array. By saying `! || !` , both values have to be in the array to have the if evaluate to true.

All in all, seeing the contents of the array, I'd personally use a HashSet (assuming you want an exact match). This will create 'distinct' values and create an easy to use collection to check if a value exist. Pseudo code:

```
var PartnerTypeName = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{"PSUD", "ABCD", "SERP", "PSUD"});

if (new string[]{"PSUD","PDST","PDLR"}.Any(PartnerTypeName.Contains) && !new string[]{"SERP","Contractors"}.Any(PartnerTypeName.Contains))
{               

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your if statement you are using ! not in the right side
so it should be && not ||
what you are doing is if one of them not in the list it will pass but i think you need both of them not in the list

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it tried locally Contains will work.
Make sure your conditions are right in your case.

```
List<string> myObjects = new List<string>();
myObjects.Add("SERP");
myObjects.Add("PSUD");

    if (!myObjects.Contains("SERP"))
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider extracting this to a method and adding unit tests for different scenarios like this

```
public bool IsSomeType(string[] partnerTypeNames)
{
    if ((NameOfYourPositiveCase(partnerTypeNames)
    && (NameOfYourNegativeCase(partnerTypeNames))
    {
        /*here the logic*/
    }
}

public bool NameOfYourPositiveCase(string[] partnerTypeNames) {
    return ((partnerTypeNames.Any("PSUD".Contains)
        || partnerTypeNames.Any("PDST".Contains)
        || partnerTypeNames.Any("PDLR".Contains));
}

public bool NameOfYourNegativeCase(string[] partnerTypeNames) {
    return !partnerTypeNames.Any("SERP".Contains)
            || !partnerTypeNames.Any("Contractors".Contains);
}
```

This will allow for easier debugging and help you determine if your conditions are wrong or something else is tricking you.

I'm aware that this will not solve the problem but it may help you determining the cause.